# Make text always fit inside any sized photo/video frame ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the drawtext filter in ffmpeg to add text to a video, but depending on the frame size, the text can either be too large (parts of it not even in the video frame) or too small (barely readable). Is there a way I can make the text automatically resize itself to perfectly fit the frame?

Here I am using to just put text in the top middle right now:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "drawtext=font='Impact': text='Test Text': fontcolor=white: borderw=3: fontsize-75: x=(w-tw)/2:y=h/12-th/2" output.jpg
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles). Font size will autoscale to fit image.

1. Make `subtitles.srt`:

   ```
   1
   00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:05,000
   Text Text
   ```
2. Encode:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='Fontname=Impact,Fontsize=75,Alignment=6'" -frames:v 1 -q:v 3 output.jpg
   ```

Comment: Thanks - also do you know if it's possible, using this method, to specify the text for the subtitles without a separate subtitle file?

Comment: @pigeonburger Not that I know of.